# Can I implement iTunes / Android payment using Phonegap

Tags: ios, html, cordova, itunes

I have an app that is generated by Phonegap. it works fine, but I want to add payment to it. is that even possible using Phonegap? I just want an alert like: 0,79 euro, do you accept? No paypal or anything else

Gr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For iOS:
[iOS In-App Purchase plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/661)

For Android:
[Google Play In-app Billing](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/615)

Good luck!

**[Update]**

References updated.

Comment: Both unavailable,please fix it.

Comment: The references above only apply for phonegap build as far as I can see this.

Comment: The iOS plugin (don't know for android) works also with Cordova and PhoneGap in local mode. There's a [IndieGoGo Campaign](http://igg.me/at/cordova-iap/x/8416559) in progress (Aug-2014) about making it cross-platform iOS + Android, in case you want to contribute.

Answer (score 0):

I use:

**Android:**

com.smartmobilesoftware.inappbilling 3.0.0 Android InAppBilling
  https://github.com/poiuytrez/AndroidInAppBilling/blob/master/v3/README.md

**iOS:**

cc.fovea.plugins.inapppurchase 3.1.0 "InAppPurchase"
  https://github.com/j3k0/PhoneGap-InAppPurchase-iOS

(Cordova 3.2 and 3.5)